# Error: Need to call TestBed.initTestEnvironment() first

Tags: javascript, angular, mocking, frontend

I'm trying do a test in angular of a service.

This is my part of the code

```
describe('AddressService', () => {

  let service: AddressService;
  let injector: TestBed;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [AddressService]
    });


    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.inject(AddressService);
    httpTestingController = injector.inject(HttpTestingController);
    
    // service = TestBed.inject(AddressService);
    

  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  })

  httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  const dummyAddressListResponse = {
    data: [
      {direccion: 'address1'}, {Colas: 'queue1'},
      {direccion: 'address2'}, {Colas: 'queue2'}
    ],
  };

  it('getAddress() should return data', () => {
    service.getAddress().subscribe((res) => {
      expect(res).toEqual(dummyAddressListResponse);
    });

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(`${environment.URI}/mock-address`);
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
    req.flush(dummyAddressListResponse);
  })

});
```

At the moment of run the test **ng test --main src/app/services/address/address.service.spec.ts**

I'm seeing this error **Error: Need to call TestBed.initTestEnvironment() first**

I have searched and don't see any solution, Has it happened to someone?

Comment: `injector = getTestBed();` <= You shouldn't need this line.  You should be able to just do `TestBed.inject(AddressService)` after you have done the configuration

Comment: `httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);` <= This is probably your issue though.  It is outside of any of the typical nested methods and is directly inside the describe

Comment: It's correct, now I have other errors but I found the you mention, thank you!!

Answer (score 18):

For **jest** users - just add the following code in **setup-jest.js**.
Because jest needs to be initialized.

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed that issue but I'm not clear how?

Comment: @Liam jest needs to be initialized and this does it. setup-jest.js is called to setup global overrides like console.log or whatever one might need

Answer (score 6):

Is this using ng-packagr (i.e. an angular library)? If so you might want to check that there are no node_modules under the ./project/ folder.

This was throwing me this exact same error. The moment I deleted the node_modules under the project folder it all started to work again.

Source: https://github.com/ngneat/spectator/issues/546

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to find details about ng-packagr like this. Thank you for this comment! :)

Answer (score 4):

the first thing: `--main` shouldn't be used, it points to an entrypoint, not to a desired test, and should be `src/test.ts`.

To run a single test use the next command:

> ng test --include "app/services/address/address.service.spec.ts"

The test should be a bit different:

```js
describe('AddressService', () => {
  let service: AddressService;
  let injector: TestBed;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // let's compile TestBed first.
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [AddressService],
    }).compileComponents();

    // let's use TestBed.injector.
    service = TestBed.inject(AddressService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  })

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('getAddress() should return data', () => {
    const dummyAddressListResponse = {
      data: [
        {direccion: 'address1'}, {Colas: 'queue1'},
        {direccion: 'address2'}, {Colas: 'queue2'}
      ],
    };

    let actual: any;
    service.getAddress().subscribe((res) => actual = res);

    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(`${environment.URI}/mock-address`);
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
    req.flush(dummyAddressListResponse);

    expect(actual).toEqual(dummyAddressListResponse);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this error `setup-jest.ts` should consist of

```
import ‘jest-preset-angular/setup-jest.js’;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it must run everything from `test.ts`.

So instead of run `ng test --main src/app/services/address/address.service.spec.ts` command, just change `const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);` to `const context = require.context('./', true, /address\.service\.spec\.ts$/);` and use  `ng test` command.