# Error Testing Angular Custom Library Component: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ngModule')"

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, npm, jasmine

I'm encountering an issue while trying to test a component from my custom Angular library using Jasmine and TestBed. the component generated by the CLI, and it doesn't contain any additional code. When running my unit tests for a custom library component (AComponent), I receive the following error message in command line:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ngModule')

and this in jasmine:

[image]

app.component.spec.ts

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {AComponent} from './a.component';

describe('AComponent', () => {
    let component: AComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AComponent],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

ng-packge.json

```
{
    "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
    "dest": "../../dist/mehrshad-core",
    "lib": {
        "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "mehrshad-core",
    "version": "0.0.23",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "^15.2.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^12.2.0",
        "sweetalert2": "^11.7.28",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0"
    },
    "sideEffects": false
}
```

Comment: Does one of the answers to this question solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65397145/error-need-to-call-testbed-inittestenvironment-first

Comment: @uminder No, unfortunately. I think we need to install jasmine and karma separately for testing angular components in libraries. I'm not sure.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue after creating a new Angular library and then somehow calling "npm install" inside the library, which creates a node_modules folder.
Apparently, after deleting this inner node_modules the tests pass. Did/does this solve it for you? 
This comment helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74903074/6774877